# ES 6 React classes access to props in a getter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to access react props from a getter when using React class based components:

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isVisible: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  };

  get close () {
    // ... 
  }

  get navigation () {
    // ...
  }

  get content () {
    // HERE: this.props.isVisible is not accessable???
    return (this.props.isVisible) ? (
      <div>
        {this.close}
        {this.navigation}
        {this.footer}
      </div>
    ) : null;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <TransitionGroup
        transitionName={{
          enter: "menu-mobile--enter",
          enterActive: "menu-mobile--enterActive",
          leave: "menu-mobile--leave",
          leaveActive: "menu-mobile--leaveActive"
        }}
        transitionEnterTimeout={200}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={200}>
        {this.content}
      </TransitionGroup>
    );    
  }
}
```

The code above thrown an error on `this.props.isVisible` it is not accessable.

I know this is possible somehow...

This is the error the consoles gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isVisible' of undefined
```

Comment: What makes you think that the value is not accessible?

Comment: @FelixKling Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isVisible' of undefined

Comment: Mmh, I don't see why `this` shouldn't refer to the component... :-/

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Is that the only location where you access `.content`? Does it work when it's a method not a getter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the es6 class definition, `this` does not refer to your component; there are some exceptions to this that I don't remember of the top of my head.

To counter this: bind your methods to `this` in your components constructor.

```
export default class Menu extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.content = this.content.bind(this);
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding